How can I use MongoDB transactions in a local Docker container?
I am developing a web application that communicates with MongoDB, so I am using docker to develop/test locally.
My docker compose is like this:
services:
  auth-terrai:
    image: auth-app
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile
    command: air -c .air.toml
    volumes:
      - ../:/app
      - ../:/go/src/gitlab.com/main/server
    ports:
      - 8080:80
      - 10000:2345
    environment:
      - VERSION=0.0.1
      - TITLE= App
      - DESCRIPTION=
      - ENVIRONMENT=dev
      - HOST=localhost:8080
      - WHITE_LIST=./key/white_list.json
      - FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT=./key/service_account.json
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb://abc123:abc123@urt-mongo-db:27017
      - MONGODB_NAME=auth
    networks:
      - urt-guane

  urt-mongo-db:
    image: mongo
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: abc123
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: abc123
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: auth
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - urt-mongo-db:/data/db
    networks:
      - urt-guane

volumes:
  urt-mongo-db:
    external: true

networks:
  urt-guane:
    external: true

In a flow of my application, I need to use transactions, but I get this error:
Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos

As I understand it, I must have a set of replicas to be able to use transactions. I really only want 1 replica, I just need to be able to test my flow. I was following several examples but it hasn't worked for me. How should I modify my docker compose to be able to use transactions?
UPDATE:
I tried this:
urt-mongo-db:
    image: mongo
    command: ["--replSet", "rs0", "--bind_ip_all", "--port", "27017", "--keyFile", "/etc/mongo/mongodb-keyfile"]
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: abc123
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: abc123
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: auth
      MONGO_INITDB_REPLICA_SET_NAME: rs0
      MONGO_INITDB_ENABLE_MONGODB_AUTH: 'yes'
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    healthcheck:
      test: echo "try { rs.status() } catch (err) { rs.initiate({_id:'rs0',members:[{_id:0,host:'host.docker.internal:27017'}]}) }" | mongo --port 27017 --quiet
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      start_period: 0s
      retries: 30
    volumes:
      - urt-mongo-db:/data/db
      - ./mongodb-keyfile:/etc/mongo/mongodb-keyfile
    networks:
      - urt-guane

But now I get this error:
docker-urt-mongo-db-1  | {"t":{"$date":"2024-05-15T22:05:57.002+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"QUERY",    "id":23799,   "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Aggregate command executor error","attr":{"error":{"code":26,"codeName":"NamespaceNotFound","errmsg":"Unable to retrieve storageStats in $collStats stage :: caused by :: Collection [local.oplog.rs] not found."},"stats":{},"cmd":{"aggregate":"oplog.rs","cursor":{},"pipeline":[{"$collStats":{"storageStats":{"waitForLock":false,"numericOnly":true}}}],"$db":"local"}}}


No idea about your problem, but if you only need test transactions, there is an alternative you can use (I have tried, and it worked). In brief, it involves the following steps: 1. create a docker network; 2. start three instances of MongoDB; 3. Init the replica set. More details here.

In the end I realized that the easiest way to test my transactions was with an M0 cluster and that's it.
